# recommended way to add a sitemap for google webmaster with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-search-console

I am trying to add a sitemap to my app using google webmaster tool . I did a quick search but couldn't find any suggestion on how to add it with Rails 4 ? does anyone have a guide or a suggestion on how to add a sitemap for Rails 4 ?

Comment: last answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810478/recommended-way-or-plugin-to-create-google-sitemaps-for-ruby-on-rails-app

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on the application, rather than on rails. The simplest approach is to develop an API that exposes all the resources based on their route. However deciding what resources you have to put in the sitemap is a completely manual process.